# What makes a classifier linear?

Tags: classification

Firstly, can a classifier be considered a linear classifier if, when plotted, it can be represented by a straight line?

Also, do linear classifiers always have only 2 classes? (either side of the line)

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178522/why-knn-is-a-non-linear-classifier/178524#178524

Comment: why do you want it to be linear?

Comment: @Matemattica I've created a system based on a linear SVM. I want to comment on it's pros and cons. And for that I need to know what defines a linear classifier.