# What is the relation between Linear Classifier and Linear Decission Boundary (or Non Linear Decision Boundary)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayes-optimal-classifier, decision-boundary

As we know (Wikipedia Definition): **Linear Classifier makes a classification decision based on the linear combination of the feature vectors.**
Mathematically  :  $y = f(\sum w_i x_i)$
So , $f$ is our linear classifier (which may be logistic or any other function). Now this linear classifier creates a decision boundary.

Now, for example consider only two features(X1, X2) :
If the decision boundary is straight line then we say its linear decision boundary otherwise non linear decision boundary.

So, my question :
**(1) If a classifier is a linear then it creates a linear decision boundary and vice versa.**
**(2) Non linear classifier always creates non linear decision boundary**

Does the above statements are true if not then please explain? I have seen so many examples , like for SVM classifier, we transform the data to higher dimension and get the hyperplane in feature space but in input space it has non linear decision boundary.
**So, what is the exact relation between a classifier and decision boundary, especially in the linear case?**

Comment: Neither statement is generally true.  The subtlety is that a nonlinear classifier may, by accident, create a linear boundary.  Thus, the appearance of a linear boundary in one specific application does not determine whether the classifier *as a procedure* is linear or not.  Also, the appearance of a linear manifold at some point in executing a procedure does not necessarily make the *entire* procedure a linear one.

Comment: @whuber  I got your explanation. So its all depend on the situations  , both  linear  and non linear classifier can create any type of decision boundaries. Even thought logistic regression can create non linear decission boundaries too( if extra features are added) . Pls correct me if some thing is not true.

Comment: @whuber Pls refer to these [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178522/why-knn-is-a-non-linear-classifier), the explanations are conflicting. Still I am not able to understand the concept of linear classifier. How do we know a classifier is linear ?

Comment: The answer you reference is a little sloppy because it lacks a suitable quantifier.  You have to understand it as meaning *all* boundaries are linear, no matter what the inputs might be.

Comment: @whuber Your time and help would be highly appreciated if you share any blog or reading material through which I gain these concept- Linear and Non Linear Classifier . Linear and Non Decision Boundaries.  Even today I asked the question in different style on Data Science Community, but didnt get response. Have a look on [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97553/does-linear-classifier-creates-linear-decision-boundary-in-the-input-feature-spa?noredirect=1#comment101823_97553)